# How to take input from console in java separated by comma and space?

Tags: java

I want to take input from the console firstly, an integer and then an array of integer separated by comma and space.
The input is as follows:
5

55, 24, 32, 22, 89

and my code is:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //code
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[num];
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    line = line.replaceAll(" ","");
    String[] temp = line.split(",");
    for(String i :temp)
    {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

but it is showing InputMismatchException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `sc.nextLine();` before `String line = sc.nextLine();`

Try this code :-

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // code
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[num];
    sc.nextLine(); // advance to new line
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    line = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String[] temp = line.split(",");
    for (String i : temp) {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
5
55, 24, 32, 22, 89
55 24 32 22 89
```